# Detect single tap on top left of screen

Tags: java, android, gesture, gesturedetector

What i'm looking to do is detect when the user has touched a certain part of the screen, the top left corner. I've looked though the documentation

developer.android.GestureDetector and developer.android.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener

I though of using onSingleTap() but have no idea how it would detect where it was touched. 
Any help of ideas would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put a space widget on your layout and size it and place it where you want. Then in your Java code, you can use a plain `setOnClickListener`.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <Space
      android:id="@+id/top_corner_space"
      android:layout_width="50dp"
      android:layout_height="50dp"
      android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then in your class:

```
Space space = (Space) findViewById(R.id.top_corner_space);
space.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, helped me a lot!